# Python, json, appending to one line dictionary {}{}{}{}{}, how do i read them one by one?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to create some simple cfg file whit

```
import json
#write "function"
exDict = {}
data = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', }
exDict = {"yellow": 'apple', "square": 'ball'}
#Corrected typo
with open('CONFIG', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(exDict))
     file.write(json.dump(data))
     file.write(json.dumps(exDict))
     file.write(json.dump(data))
```

Read functions trayed:

open and read the file after the appending:

```
f = open("CONFIG", "r")
print(f.read())
Out
{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}{"A": "a", "B": "b"}{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}{"A": "a", "B": "b"}
```

Now the file contains:

```
{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}{"A": "a", "B": "b"}{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}{"A": "a", "B": "b"}
#dont work if i try to 
with open("CONFIG", "r") as CFG:
result = json.loads("CFG")
print(result)

#error code:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

On the same line
"{}{}{}{}"
when i try to extract all of them, the Ide throw an error dha...

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line "X" column "X" (char "X")
```

I read a loot of "past 3h searching" not finding this particular case a loot of "line by line parsing" but i have only one line,i would like to keep it like this so i can learn why end how
so my question is:

how do i extract one dictionary at the time?

how do i extract all of them together?

there is a way to extract the 2-3 dict in particular whit out extracting all?

Comment: your passing a string "CFG" to the json.loads `result = json.loads("CFG")` you want to pass the file handle `result = json.loads(CFG)`

Comment: You can't read it with `json.loads` because the content of the file is not valid JSON.

Comment: At least use the "JSON-lines" format, which puts one JSON object per line. Then you can read the file line by line and decode each line individually. As is, you'd need to invent your own not-a-JSON parser.

Comment: You should find a way to write the config in one go, with a single call to `json.dumps()`.     `file.write(json.dumps(entire_config))`

Comment: @Håken Better yet: `json.dump(entire_config, file)`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues with the code you shared:

1. <strike>The file you are writing to is called `CONFG` (the capital "i" is missing) while the file you are reading from is called `CONFIG`. I'm assuming this is just a typo here and not in your actual code.</strike> FIXED
2. When you are writing the `dict`s into the file, you are using both `json.dump()` and `json.dumps()`. When using `json.dump()` you need to provide a file object, so I'm assuming this is a typo in the code here.
3. You are writing one `dict` at a time. That way `file.write()` will just append it to the file, which will lead to a series of JSON objects in one line. This is not wrong per-se, it just doesn't conform the actual JSON standard, and therefore the standard JSON library won't be able to deal with it, which is probably not what you want. If you want to make this to work, you could consider writing one JSON object **per line** (which is sometimes called [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/)).
4. The line

   ```python
   result = json.loads("CFG")
   ```

   gives you the error because you are passing in the string `"CFG"` rather than the file object `CFG`, and even if you did pass in the file object, it wouldn't work because you would need to use `json.load()` (without the **`s`**) **and** because you are writing the JSON objects into one line (as per 3.).

With all of the above, there are different ways to make this work:

## JSON Lines

The first suggestion is to write each `dict` as one JSON object per line in the output file, e.g.:

```python
import json

data = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', }
exDict = {'yellow': 'apple', 'square': 'ball'}

# Write the dicts to a file, one JSON object per line:
with open('CONFIG.jsonl', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(exDict))
     file.write('\n')
     file.write(json.dumps(data))
     file.write('\n')
     file.write(json.dumps(exDict))
     file.write('\n')
     file.write(json.dumps(data))
     file.write('\n')

# CONFIG.jsonl now contains:
#{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}
#{"A": "a", "B": "b"}
#{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}
#{"A": "a", "B": "b"}

# Read the file and parse one JSON line at a time:
dicts_from_json_lines = []
with open('CONFIG.jsonl', 'r') as CFG:
     for line in CFG.readlines():
         dicts_from_json_lines.append(json.loads(line))
```

## List of JSON Objects

Another way would be to store the `dict`s in a `list` and to write that `list` as JSON into the file, e.g.:

```python
import json

data = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'b', }
exDict = {'yellow': 'apple', 'square': 'ball'}

list_of_dicts = [data, exDict]

# Write the list of dicts to a file:
with open('CONFIG.json', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(list_of_dicts))

# CONFIG.json now contains:
# [{"yellow": "apple", "square": "ball"}, {"A": "a", "B": "b"}]

# Read the file:
with open('CONFIG.json', 'r') as CFG:
   dicts_from_json = json.load(CFG)
#  or alternatively:
#  dicts_from_json = json.loads(CFG.read())
```

Comment: 1:it's typo in the question not in the code,Corrected

2:Im gonna try correct it, noting new..

3: EXACTLY, HOW DO I DEAL WHIT THEM?
    whit out adding file.write('\n')
   this is the question my question

4: Thanks for the code but i'm trying to avoid using  file.write('\n') so it's speed up on writing, i don't care about the reading and processing speed per se but i care, about the writing speed.

Comment: "i know it's not gonna be that mach of a difference in speed,  but i'm training to learn to process one line dictionary for future problem like if some api give me this kind of problem ecc.."

Comment: It's very unlikely that an API will return this type of data structure (i.e. JSON objects on one line). Most likely it is going to return a JSON object or a list of JSON objects (which is still valid JSON).

Comment: I've added another solution, maybe it's more in line with what you'd like to achieve.